# Unable to locate package libcfitsio3

Tags: bash, ubuntu, dependencies, package, locate

I am trying to install the presto pulsar software.

I am at the first step in which I have to install some packages.  I am entering the following command:

"sudo apt-get install git libfftw3-bin libfftw3-dbg libfftw3-dev libfftw3-doc libfftw3-double3 libfftw3-long3 libfftw3-quad3 libfftw3-single3 pgplot5 csh automake gfortran libglib2.0-dev libccfits-dev libcfitsio3 libcfitsio3-dev"

I have tried navigating over to the ubuntu website to search for libscfitsio and I found some libscfitsio packages on the ubuntu website but I don't understand how to install them through the bash shell.  This an image of the errors that I have received:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhDCb.png)

Unable to locate package libcfitsio3

Package libcfitsio3-dev has no installation candidate

I have tried entering all the variations of libcfitsio into the bash shell.  I always get the error "Unable to locate package libcfitsio."  What I don't understand is if I went on the ubuntu website and I searched for libcfitsio and I got some results on the ubuntu website, why is the shell unable to locate anything?

Comment: Your question is better suited to [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/tour). This site is for programming related questions.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that **there's no package in the name `libcfitsio3`** in the ubuntu repository. See my results with ubuntu command `apt search` down below. In fact there's couple of packages related to `libcfitsio` and it shows there's updated version **`libcfitsio7`**`. You can install any of those according to your requirement.

[image]

PS: You don't have to search all those sites for package availabily.  `apt search <name>` lists all your required packages from the main repository. Just make sure you run `apt update` to update to fetch latest from the remote repositories.

Answer (score 0):

relevant package name is libcfitsio-dev, so use:

```
sudo apt-get install libcfitsio-dev
```

I used the above to install cfitsio via GitHub Actions with ubuntu-latest